# What is the plural of 'Beton'? Is there one?

Tags: grammatical-number

I am a german native speaker, but I'm not sure if there even is a plural of 'Beton'. So I started searching and the result is inconclusive.

[Duden.de](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Beton) does not list a plural the way it does for other words, but it does list the variant "Betone" which sounds like a plural.

> der Beton; Genitiv: des Betons, (Arten:) Betons, besonders süddeutsch, österreichisch Betone [beˈtoːnə]

Putting "Plural Beton" into google, it shows quite a few sites that list "Betone" as the plural. Some list "Betons" as the plural. Some even list both like [this site](https://www.verbformen.de/deklination/substantive/Beton.htm), which mentions it to be rare.

Comment: Wenn deine Muttersprache Deutsch ist, solltest du deine Fragen hier lieber auf Deutsch stellen. Zum einen ist dies hier ein Deutsch-Forum, und zum anderen werden hier mehr als 95% aller Antworten von deutschen Muttersprachlern gegeben. Weil es aber die Regel gibt, dass man Antworten und Kommentare in derselben Sprache verfassen soll, in der auch die Frage gestellt wurde, erzwingst du mit einer englischen Frage, dass sich dann lauter deutsche Muttersprachler in Englisch miteinander unterhalten, wobei das Thema aber die deutsche Sprache ist. Das ist absurd und sollte vermieden werden.

Comment: The answer is right there in the question: The plural of *Beton* – used to talk about types of concrete – is ***Betons*** or, particularly in South Germany and Austria, ***Betone***. Source: Duden.de

Comment: @HubertSchölnast das tut mir leid, ich habe mich an den anderen Fragen orientiert die ich auf der Startseite gesehen habe und die waren englisch . Ich wollte original auf deutsch fragen.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel do you have a different version of Duden.de than my link? I cannot find the word plural on the page even using browser page search.

Comment: @findusl Was meinst Du denn, was "Arten" heißt?

Comment: Welche Sprache: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/830/1487

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich glaube es dir schon, ich wusste es nur vorher nicht. Ich bin es gewohnt mich auf Stackexchangeseiten an deren anderen Fragen zu orientieren die ich sehe. Hättest du gerne dass ich die Frage auf Deutsch umschreibe?

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Ich weiß nicht genau was es hier heißt. Ich weiß nur bei anderen Wortdefinitionen wird "Plural" benutzt wenn von "Plural" gesprochen wird. Ich vermute Arten sind regionale Unterschiede.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(English version below)

Das ist bei unzählbaren Wörtern öfter so: eigentlich gibt es keinen Plural, aber wenn es dann um "Sorten von ..." geht, also um so eine Art Metaebene, bildet sich doch ein Plural heraus.

Beispiele:

**Milch**: eigentlich kein Plural, aber die Drogerie bietet verschiedene ["Milche zur Gesichtspflege"](https://www.reformmarkt.com/kosmetik/gesicht/gesichtspflege/milche.html) an.

**Bedarf**: es gibt entweder einen Bedarf für etwas oder keinen, aber wenn über verschiedene Dinge gesprochen wird, für die es jeweils einen Bedarf gibt, sind es "Bedarfe" (z.B. ["Bedarfe strukturieren"](https://www.betterplace.org/c/hilfe/bedarfe-strukturieren)).

**Beton**: unzählbares Wort, aber im Baubedarf gibt es für verschiedene Zwecke dann doch [verschiedene Betone](https://www.baunetzwissen.de/beton/fachwissen/eigenschaften/betone-mit-besonderen-eigenschaften-150938) zu kaufen.

Wenn die Pluralnutzung selten ist, können auch verschiedene Pluralbildungen parallel existieren. Für mich klingt "Betons" falsch, aber das entscheide ja nicht ich, sondern letztlich, was sich irgendwann durchsetzt.

---

This is often the case with uncountable words: originally, there is no plural, but when it comes to "varieties of ...", i.e. a kind of meta-level, a plural does emerge.

Examples:

**Milch**: originally an uncountable word, but drugstores offer various "Milche" for facial care.

**Bedarf**: there is either a "Bedarf" for something or there is not, but when talking about different things for each of which there is a "Bedarf", the plural "Bedarfe" is used.

**Beton**: uncountable word, but building supply shops offer different "Betone" (sorts of concrete) for different purposes.

If the use of plural is rare, different plural forms can exist in parallel. To me, "Betons" sounds wrong, but that's not for me to decide, but by what will eventually prevail.

Comment: Auch wenn findusl sagt er ist ein deutscher Muttersprachler, solte diese Antwort auf Englisch sein: [Principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) [Meta Post](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/should-the-language-of-an-answer-match-the-language-used-in-the-question/)

Comment: Tut mir sehr leid die Verwirrung mit der Sprache. Ich habe mich an den ersten Fragen orientiert die ich gesehen habe und die waren englisch :/

Answer (score 3):

Ich würde sagen, das Betone ein Fachbegriff ist. Für jemanden, der sich mit Baumaterialen auskennt und über mehrere Arten von Beton sprechen möchte, ist Betone im Kontext der korrekte Plural.

Im Gegensatz dazu ist in der Alltagssprache Beton gleich Beton und es gibt keinen Plural. Wenn von mehreren Gegenständen aus Beton die Rede ist, wird der Plural des Gegenstandes gebildet und nicht der von Beton. In diesem Kontext existiert kein Plural von Beton.